# connection link failure mysql

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to my android device with my mysql database, I can do it in local (from a emulation device) but when I use my IP to connect to with my mobile I get:

```
Communication Link failure
The last packet send succesfully to the server was 0 millisecond ago. The driver has not recived any packet from the server
```

my code is:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://MYIP:3306/BD", "USER", "USER");
```

with localhost it works:

```
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2:3306/BD", "USER", "USER");
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is your phone hooked up to the same network as your computer?

Answer (score 0):

To connect your Android device to **Mysql** you should use **webs ervices**. you can find more information in this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

the Tutorial use PHP to creat web services, however you can use any other server side language to connect with mysql database, this will return JSON data that you can parse it to in your android app

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a network issue, if the devices are in the same LAN don't use your internet IP. Or even if the devices are in different network your router could be blocking your connection.